# Keras model `logits` and `labels` must have same shape (None, 2) vs (None, 1)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model trained for occupancy detection of parking spaces, which I load using `keras.models.load_model(PATH_TO_MODEL)`. The input for the model is a `224 x 224` RGB image. This is the model structure as output of `keras.plot_model(...)`:
[image]

I then compile the loaded model using this line of code:
`loaded_model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')`

And then I begin the training process using a custom image generator:

```
def image_generator(input_path:str, bs:int, mode:str='train', img_size:int=224, aug=None):
    file_path = os.path.join(OCD_DATA_DIR, 'splits', input_path, 'all.txt')
    f = open(file_path, 'r')

    while True:
        images = []
        labels = []

        while len(images) < bs:
            line = f.readline()
            if line == '':
                f.seek(0)
                line = f.readline()
                if mode == 'eval':
                    break

            image_path, label = line.strip().split(' ')
            # print(image_path)
            image_path = os.path.join(OCD_DATA_DIR, input_path, image_path)
            image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED) * 1. / 255
            image = cv2.resize(image, (img_size, img_size))

            images.append(image)
            labels.append(label)

        if aug is not None:
            (images, labels) = next(aug.flow(np.array(images), labels, batch_size=bs))

        labels = np.array(labels).astype('float32')

        yield (np.array(images), labels)


generator = image_generator(SvJur_PATH, 64)

history = loaded_model.fit(
    x = generator,
    steps_per_epoch = NUM_TRAIN_IMAGES // 64,
    epochs = 18)
```

I am getting this error:

> ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received
> ((None, 2) vs (None, 1)).

Edit: I have concluded that I can just add a layer to the end of my model so that it has the desired output shape. I do it like this:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
for layer in loaded_model.layers: # go through all layers
    model.add(layer)
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='softmax'))
```

But when I compare the predicted values, they do not seem to match:

```
0.92 0.08
1.00 0.00
1.00 0.00
0.89 0.11
0.41 0.59
```

Versus the new model predictions:

```
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
[1.]
```

Comment: If you want to use `binary_crossentropy` as your loss function, then the output of your model (last dimension of your last layer) should be 1, not 2. you can either change your last layer to something like `Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")` or change your loss function to `categorical_crossentropy` and the activation function to softmax.  It depends on the shape of the data you have.

Comment: The activation function of the last layer ('score') is `softmax`, but even when I run it with `categorical_crossentropy` it does not work and results in the same error. I also tried using `from_logits=True / False` but it did not help either.

Comment: Please share the exact model definition code to understand the issue. The above value error depicts that your dataset has one label but you have defined no of labels as two in the model definition. Also please share the model compilation code.